# How to assign a Vim as the default program for a file type and run it in maximized terminal?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gnome-terminal, default-programs

I want to assign a terminal based program as a default program in Gnome Shell 3.2. I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

More specifically, I want my .txt files to open in vim with maximized Gnome Terminal.

The 'Open with other application' menu does not provide for this.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For files handling in gnome you will have to use the graphical version of `vim` called `gvim`, to install it type `sudo apt-get install vim-gnome`.

Has an option you can create a `.desktop` file that will be listed on 'Open with other application' tab:

- Navigate to `~/.local/share/applications`
- Create a file called `vim-console.desktop` with these contents:

> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Encoding=UTF-8
> Name=Vim Text Editor (Console)
> Comment=Edit text files in a console using Vim
> Exec=gnome-terminal --full-screen --execute bash -c "vim %u"
> Terminal=true
> Type=Application
> Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/vim.svg
> Categories=Application;Utility;TextEditor;
> StartupNotify=true
> MimeType=text/plain;
> NoDisplay=true
> ```

After this you will see *Vim Text Editor (Console)* in your *Open with other application* tab, select it and when you double click the file you will be able to open it using vim terminal editor.

Answer (score 4):

I found another solution as above solution didn't work for me (I don't know why).

Create a file `mvim` in `/usr/bin/` by:

```
sudo vim /usr/bin/mvim
```

And paste the following two lines:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e "/usr/bin/vim $1"
```

Press `:wq` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save.

Now give executable permissions to this your command by:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/mvim
```

To test if it's gonna work or not, you can type:

```
mvim anyfile
```

It should open a new terminal with `anyfile` opened in vim.

Now open your `file manager` (mine is SpaceFM) and `right click` a text file and click `Properties`. If there is an option of open with command then type in the path to your command i.e. `/usr/bin/mvim`.

And yay! meanwhile you created your own command!

Comment: You'll run into trouble with filenames with spaces. Use `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e "/usr/bin/vim '$1'"`, or `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x /usr/bin/vim "$1"`. Better yet, use `-x` and `$@`: `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x /usr/bin/vim "$@"`, in case you want to pass options to Vim, or open multiple files.

Comment: Thanks for the information, muru. I am using `lxterminal` as of now. Is there any alternative for -x flag or something to make multiple files thing work for me.

Comment: @MandeepSingh Care to try `xfce4-terminal`? It's also lightweight, and supports `-x`.